# Push button's with NSGraphiteControlTint

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

I want to change button tint from Aqua to Graphite. Why this code doesn't work?

```
[[myButton cell] setControlTint:NSGraphiteControlTint];
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do it for one your control. I think something was changed in setControlTint work rules in OS 10.6 and later. But it's only hypothesis.

In any case you can try to use this code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:NSGraphiteControlTint forKey:@"AppleAquaColorVariant"
```

But remember that it should be insert before `NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);` You can also create subclass for your application class and change default settings in `init` method.

You can also set graphite theme for concrete window:

```
NSColorSpace* space = [NSColorSpace genericGrayColorSpace];
[_window setColorSpace:space];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that the specific `NSCell` subclass you're using doesn't make use of the `controlTint` (and for `NSButtonCell` I don't think every `buttonType` supports the controlTint), I don't think all .  With the direction Apple is taking in its recent UI I wouldn't be surprised if this eventually becomes deprecated.

If you *do* need a cell with a different tint, you could always subclass it and implement it directly.

Comment: I subclassing cell for myButton and implement code "[self setControlTint:NSGraphiteControlTint];" in awakeFromNib method, but this haven't effect.